# Load model from snapshot in the Flow environment

Tags: flow-project

Repost from Flow user "ml jack":

I'm in the process of RL training with flow and rllab. Snapshots are periodically saved. Is there a way to load these snapshot and test/re-evaluate them in the flow environment?

Comment: "_Repost from Flow user "ml jack_": It would be better if you provided instead the link from which your problem originated from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Flow Team -----

"Yes! So if you look in the [tutorials](https://github.com/flow-project/flow/tree/master/tutorials), there's a tutorial on [visualizing](https://github.com/flow-project/flow/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial05_visualize.ipynb).

Basically, run python visualizer_rllab.py path/to/pkl and that should do it! Note: you have to specify which pkl file you want in the path as in python visualizer_rllab.py path_to_pkl/name_of_pkl_file. Advanced usage should be described in the tutorial."